# how make z3 checking faster or see progress

Tags: python, z3

I am trying to check satisfiability of some formulas with z3 python API using

```
import z3
s=z3.Solver()
s.add(formula)
result=s.check()
```

With some formulas the method-call solver.check() keeps running for very long time. I do not know if it halted or it would have returned if I waited longer. Is there any way see the progress of checking of satisfiability? Is there any way to make the checking of the satisfiability faster (for example by adding some guides how to check it more specifically)?

Answer (score 2):

Not in general, no.

Notice that you're solving essentially an NP-Complete problem. There's really no indication as to how much you've "progressed" unless you do a pure enumeration, which would be pointless except for finite and tiny problems anyhow.

There are "tricks" to code more efficiently certain kinds of problems so the solver goes faster; but for us to be able to advise you on that, you'll have to share some examples of what problems you're trying to solve and how you're modeling them.

Comment: Is it possible to get any information about what z3 has done so far to try check of the satisfiability? I am mostly interested about fasting check of the satisfiabilit of equation, that contain quatifiers. like solve(And(Exists([x1],A(x1)),Not(Exists([x1],A(x1))))) .

Comment: You can run it with high-verbosity (`z3 -v:10`) which will print out a log of what it's doing. But what it prints will not be easy to read/analyze nor stable over the long run.

Comment: Also note that quantifier reasoning is a soft-spot for SMT solvers. If your statements are essentially about quantified first-order logic formulae, you're better off using a proper theorem prover like Isabelle, Coq, etc.

Comment: @allas, how to run it with high-verbosity using z3's python API?

Comment: Add `z3.set_option(verbose=10)` after the `import z3` line. As I mentioned before, the verbose output will really not be that useful/readable unless you're intimately familiar with z3 internals.